# Get how much of a page has loaded in WebView component in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to know how much of a web-page has loaded in a React Native WebView component? I want to show a loading progress for a page loading in my WebView.

Comment: maybe you can inject a js code to webview that send postmessage in interval and use that js massage too know percentage loaded , but it seems it can't be done cause js run only on page load once

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to do what you ask with the react native web view, you need to implement a fake progress bar yourself.

However, you can use the react native wkwebview component (https://github.com/CRAlpha/react-native-wkwebview) that offers a handy onProgress method:

```
<WKWebView onProgress={(progress) => console.log(progress)} />
```

Note that this onProgress method only works on iOs.

I personally prefer using this component instead of the react native web view as it feels much faster and offers more useful methods.